# Getting an access denied trying to mount a VHDX to wsl on Windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, wsl2

I created a new VHDX using disk manager, and I'm trying to mount it to WSL2 (version 1.0.3), running the following command:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 --mount --vhd D:\wsl2\wsl2-drive.vhdx --bare
```

It fails with:

```
Failed to attach disk '\\?\D:\wsl2\wsl2-drive.vhdx' to WSL2: Access is denied.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/MountVhd/E_ACCESSDENIED
```

Things I tried which didn't make a difference:

- Run it from an elevated PowerShell
- Create a VHD instead of a VHDX
- Leaving out `--bare`
- Leaving out `-d Ubuntu-22.04`
- Having the VHDX is various different states:

  - "Not Initialized / Unallocated": the state after creating in disk manager
  - Choose 'Initialize disk' in Disk Manager
  - Create a partition (but that feels wrong, since it shouldn't be NTFS for Linux?)
  - Detach it altogether in Disk Manager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*<sub>Solved via the comments, so moving the information to an answer (with some additional info).</sub>*

The (relatively) new WSL error messages were useful in this case.  The `Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/MountVhd/E_ACCESSDENIED` indicated a permissions problem of *some* sort.

Normally, as far as I can tell, a `.vhdx` file created through Disk Management will be owned by the local Administrators group.  In most cases, the local user that installed and runs WSL is a member of this group, so there are permission issues.

However, in this case, that *seems* not to be the case, since changing the owner of the `.vhdx` ultimately solved the `ACCESSDENIED` error.

A few additional items:

- The virtual disk *does* need to be detached from Disk Management (Right-Click -> *Detach VHD*) or the following error will occur:

  ```
  Failed to attach disk '<path_to>\wsl2-drive.vhdx' to WSL2: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
  Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/MountVhd/0x80070020
  ```
- I personally recommend creating the `.vhdx` from an Administrative PowerShell account using:

  ```
  new-vhd -Dynamic -SizeBytes 100gb -BlockSizeBytes 1mb -path <path_to>/<name>.vhdx
  ```

  The block size turns out to be pretty important in how quickly the dynamic disk will grow.  The 1 mb block size is what WSL uses for its built-in virtual disks.
- Also, `--bare` is required as long as there is no filesystem on the drive that WSL can handle.  Your next step is going to be to create a filesystem on that virtual drive from *within* WSL.  As mentioned in the [WSL doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#attaching-the-disk-without-mounting-it), use `lsblk` to identify the newly mounted disk.

  It's not a bad idea to be completely sure that you are formatting the proper device by unmounting, `lsblk`, then remount and `lsblk` again.  The new device will be obvious in that case.  Of course, a unique drive size is a valid way to identify it as well.

  Once you've identified the device, you will use something like:

  ```
  sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/<device> # e.g. sde
  ```
- After you create a filesystem on the device, as long as the filesystem is one that WSL2 recognizes (`ext4`, `btrfs`, and probably a few others), you can skip the `--bare` option on future mounts.

  At that point, it's a good idea to switch to using `--name <name>` so that the partition/filesystem will be mounted in a known location.  By default, this will be `/mnt/wsl/<name>`.
- The `-d Ubuntu-22.04` in this case is a no-op.  I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't generate an error, but the device is always mounted into *all* distributions, regardless of whether you specify a distro using `wsl -d` or not.

Comment: This answer was a precious gem on the Internet that summarizes many important points that are hard to find. BUT information was lost in the comments that were deleted, so I am left stuck!

I am getting the error, but don't know what to do as far as changing the owner. Were you a local administrator? What did you change ownership to? I am administrator so I'm surprised this is failing.

Comment: Well, I tried to add my personal account name to the ACL (in Windows, right click on vhdx file, Properties, Security, Edit, Add, Advanced, Find Now, find your personal account in the list, ok, give yourself full control, ok.

That worked. Is this what you did too? What's weird about this is that wsl --mount was being run from an elevated prompt so that seems weird that it would fail.

Comment: @DanielRussell Honestly, the original poster solved it based on my guidance in the comments.  The actual permissions were never actually listed in the comments, but I'm fairly sure the *owner* was listed as the Administrator, but oddly the *user* did have full permissions.  Only changing the owner fixed the issue for the OP.  It's a bit odd (and kind of the converse of your odd case, yes), which is why I personally was never able to confirm or repeat the issue on my end.

Comment: This access denied issue happened to me after reinstalling windows. Changing permission fixed it

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had the same issue while trying to mount a backup of a wsl disk from another PC. I solved it by making a local copy.

So instead of mounting directly from an external drive, made a copy and then mount the drive using the command :

```
wsl -d Ubuntu --mount -vhd ext4.vhdx --name backup
```

NB: since the backup is already formated, do not use `--bare` in this case. The drive will appear in `/mnt/wsl/backup/`